# Join audio files into one mp3?

Tags: audio, mp3

I have a bunch of mp3 files I would like to consolidate into a single mp3. What software is able to do this quick and effectively? I have tried online conversion tools and they don't work so well. I looked at Helium Audio Joiner and I think it will do what I want, but is there a standard tool for this out there already? I don't want Audacity or any tool where I have to manually fit in each track. I just want them joined at the end.

Comment: This is one way using Audacity: http://forum.audacityteam.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=41432

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried this in [Reaper](http://www.reaper.fm/download.php).  If you drag and drop the files onto a new project it will prompt you for what you want to do with the files.  You will need to make sure that you have the files sorted in the order you want them in Windows Explorer before you drag and drop them into Reaper.

[image]

If you select Single Track it will put all of the mp3 files end to end on a single track.  You can then render the output to whatever format you desire.

**This process will decode and re-encode the mp3 files** and will cause some quality loss as compared to the originals.  If there is software out there that can combine the files without re-encoding them that is probably the way to go.  If not, this is a simple way to get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but it's a portable app that does what you need and has quite a lot of downloads. It's not an editor, it seems like a program that is designed just for this specific task.

http://download.cnet.com/Merge-MP3/3000-2169_4-10410936.html

Answer (score 0):

[AVS Audio converter](http://avs-video-suite.org) can merge audio files into one.